# Java regex split double from string

Tags: java, regex, string, split, double

I am having a problem splitting something like the following string:

43.80USD

What I want is to be able to split the expression into an array that has "43.80" as the first element and "USD" as the second. So the result would be something like:

["43.80", "USD"]

I am sure there is some way to do this with regex, but I am not proficient enough with it to figure it out on my own. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the format of your string is fixed you can split it as follows

```
String[] currency = "48.50USD".split("(?<=\\d)(?=[a-zA-Z])");
System.out.println("Amount='"+currency[0]+"'; Denomination='"+currency[1]+"'");
// prints: Amount='48.50'; Denomination='USD'
```

The regex above uses a *[positive look-behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind)* (?<=) and a *[positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookahead)* (?=) to find a separator (which is of *zero-length* here) that's preceded with a number and followed by a letter.

Answer (score 1):

If your data really looks like `"43.80USD"` then you can use

```
"43.80USD".split("(?i)(?=[a-z])",2)
```

- `(?=[a-z])` will split before any of `a-z` characters
- `(?i)` will make used regex case-insensitive so it will also work for `uSd`
- second argument is max size of result array, since you don't want `["43.80", "U", "S, "D"]` but `["43.80", "USD"]` we need to use `2`.

Answer (score 0):

This regex works`(\d*\.\d*)([a-zA-Z]*)`. Group 1 will be the amount, including the decimal. Group 2 will be the USD or other monetary name. Note that this regex only requires a decimal point, everything else is optional. So this also matches: "45123.15542ABCDEFG". Group 1 will be 45123.15542 and group 2 will be ABCDEFG. If you want more strict requirements, tell me what they are and Ill put it in. Otherwise your code will look something like:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d*\\.\\d*)([a-zA-Z]*)");//Note the double \\ to escape twice.
Matcher m = p.matcher("43.80USD");
String amount, type;
if(m.matches){
    amount = m.group(1);
    type = m.group(2);
}
```

Comment: So I may be misunderstanding something, but I've tested the regex in a unit test I wrote and it returns an empty array. It doesn't seem to be splitting on the boundary between the decimal and alphabetic characters which is what I need...

Comment: @ZacharyL'Anglois I dont think you want to split around the decimal. You want to split around the last digit. Also make sure you double escaped your regex like I did in my code.